# How Do You Set Value of Input Element Programmatically Through CSharp?

Tags: c#, html, webforms, autofill, browser-automation

Hello
I am trying to automate my IE to log into a website but the problem is that the input elements do not have an HTML ID attribute! For example:

`<input type="text" name="user" size="15" value="">`

How do you program C# to insert text in this text box?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Add the following attributes to your input tag: `runat="server"` and `id="someId"`

```
<input id="user" type="text" size="15" runat="server">
```

Then server-side you do:

```
user.Text = "sample text";
```

Then you can do something like:

```
foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
{
    TextBox t = c as TextBox;

    if (t != null)
    {
        t.Text = "sample text";
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure it'll work without the `runat="server"` attribute

Comment: thanks but I don't have access to edit the HTML on the website :(

Comment: I think he's just trying to post to a different website that isn't under his control

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a bit late, but here is an alternate to the jquery method.

I assume with IE you mean the webbrowser control.
Once you have the document, you can go through the input -elements.

Something like

`HtmlElementCollection inputs = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");`

Then you loop through each of the inputs. You can check the input's name with

`input.GetAttribute("name").Equals("user")`

Inserting value to the field would be done with

`input.SetAttribute("value", "MyUserName");`

Answer (score 2):

I guess this isn't *"doing it programatically with C#"*, but you could [jQuerify](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet) the page, then run some custom javascript afterwards, to manipulate the value of the control. If you are using `WebBrowser`, you could call the below method to insert the scripts.

```
string script = "script text";
WebBrowser.Navigate(script);
```

### jQuerify code

```
var s=document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src','http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
```

### Custom code

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('input[type="text"][name="user"]').val('FooBar')});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help:-

- NB : also look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6.aspx
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx
  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?query=mshtml%20tutorial&ac=1
- Create a new project like a Windows form application project,
- Add references of MSHTML ie Microsoft HTML Object Library plus SHDocVw ie Microsoft Internet Controls,
- Create a function with body somewhat like and bound it to anything like a button's click event:

  ```
          /*INTERNET EXPLORER's OBJECT*/
          SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
  ie.Navigate("http://www.example.com/entry"); /*GO TO EXAMPLE.COM*/
          /*WAIT UNTIL THE BROWSER IS READY AND COMPLETELY LOADED*/
  while (ie.ReadyState != SHDocVw.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE) 
          {
             Application.DoEvents();
          }
          mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = ie.Document;
          while (doc.readyState != "complete")
          {
             Application.DoEvents();
          }
  /*GET ALL THE INPUT ELEMETS IN A COLLECTION*/
  MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection collection=
          doc.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
          foreach (mshtml.IHTMLElement elem in collection)
          {
            if (elem.getAttribute("name") != null)
              {
                /*IDENTIFY THE INPUT CONTROL BY NAME ATTRIBUTE*/
        if (elem.getAttribute("name").Equals("user"))
                {/*ENTER USER NAME*/
                 elem.setAttribute("value", "ABC");
        }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

As Nico said with:

```
<input id="user" type="text" size="15" runat="server">
```

but you must try:

```
user.Value = "sample text";
```

insted!