# Can I focus to another window with a VBA command in Excel 2007?

Tags: vba, excel, sendkeys

I want to run a VBA script from Excel 2007 that can switch focus to another active window (ALT+TAB) send commands to that window, and then return focus to Excel and continue to perform commands in the VBA.

For example:

Copy the contents of cell A1, focus onto an active Internet Explorer window, send the TAB key command, paste the copied data from A1, and then refocus back into Excel to continue the VBA script.

Is this possible?  I couldn't find the right information online and feel like it is possible to do this using Excel VBA.

Comment: While it is possible to do what you want in a very kludgy manner using `AppActivate` & `SendKeys` it wold be far safer for your example to either automate IE ( as suggested by JMAX) or use XMLHTTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding & using this software called [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).  It's free & open source.

It allows you to script macros using a proprietary syntax that's pretty intuitive to use.

The problem I wanted to solve was much easier to execute using AutoHotkey versus Excel VBA.

The AutoHotkey code for the above pseudo-code:

```
#space::
;Focus to Excel and copy contents of cell A1
WinActivate Microsoft Excel - filename.xls
Send {Ctrldown}{Home}{Ctrlup}
Send ^c

;Focus to Internet Explorer, TAB to the first field, and paste clipboard data into it
WinActivate Google - Windows Internet Explorer
Send {Tab}
Send ^v

;Focus back to Excel
WinActivate Microsof Excel - filename.xls
return
```

It's not worth going over the specifics of this syntax, but I just pasted it for demonstration purposes.

The program allows for a whole lot more and is worth a closer look if you need to automate tasks that require special mouse & keyboard actions across multiple windows.  Normal programming aspects such as variables & loops are supported too.

There is also more general info about the program and it's potential uses on [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey)

Comment: Please note that you can accept your own answer to "close" the topic while you seem to have found a solution to your issue. Thanks for sharing it by the way.

Comment: I was aware of this and have done so in the past, but there is a time period for which you have to let expire before accepting your own answer.  Thanks anyway

Comment: sorry, I forgot about the delay

Answer (score 2):

Within VBA itself, you **cannot literally send keys or master another application**. Yet, you can use the Microsoft APIs to simulate behavior in the Office Suite or, in some extend, to Internet Explorer.

You can either:

- use **C#** to create a Microsoft Windows level application.
  Here are some links:

  - [How Do You Set Value of Input Element Programmatically Through CSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990686/how-do-you-set-value-of-input-element-programmatically-through-csharp)
  - [In this blog post](http://www.farooqazam.net/c-sharp-auto-click-button-and-auto-fill-form/)
- use VBA and **IE APIs** to call a webpage and fill an input with the value of your Excel file.
  Here are some links:

  - on [Excely.com](http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml)
  - on [vba-corner](http://vba-corner.livejournal.com/4623.html)

Comment: That link to vba-corner actually shows you how to switch to an active IE instance, so it might be what the OP was looking for. Although I recommend simply automating IE from the beginning.